# Adding Magnolia CMS to OpenShift application

Tags: java, tomcat, openshift, magnolia

Today I have been trying to install magnolia as a Openshift application. I have tried to follow this [step-by-step guide](https://blog.openshift.com/free-magnolia-cms-hosting-on-openshift/) but all I can get is this exception in the log:

*Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Magnolia is not configured properly and therefore unable to start: real path can't be obtained [ctx real path:null]. Please refer to the Magnolia documentation for installation instructions specific to your environment.*

I have no idea how to run it.
Also whenever I recommit the git or restart the app, openshift reverts changes to server.xml and places *unpackWARs="false"* again.

Comment: So i found out what the problem was. I added a source git from github, and the repository did not contain .openshift folder. I thought the reference was on something else.
Creating a new application on openshift without connectiong to github resulted in giving me the .openshift folder with correct server.xml that did not overrwrite.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read this?

https://blog.openshift.com/free-magnolia-cms-hosting-on-openshift/

Also, where are you changing the server.xml? If you are doing it directly in your gear that will get overwritten. What you should do is go into your local git respository for the application, then into .openshift/config and there should be a server.xml in there. That is the one you should edit.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what the problem was. When creating my application in OpenShift I placed a github link for source, and that did not generate my .openshift folder in my source, and I was completely lost why my server resets the server settings.

So the solution was to create new application without using github as the source, and then i could change my server.xml that held the configuration.